# Chart JS 2.0.0 and above sets data points incorrectly so that linear Data line isn't straight

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I Need to Show linear Data in a Chart Js Line Chart.
With Chart JS 2.0.0 and above the Data Points are set incorrectley, the line which should appear straight seems to have rough edges.

As you zoom in the page, the edges become more visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/AnchaXD/q6xpyqhw/

```
var data = {
    labels :['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'July', 'August',
        'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'July',
        'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'July', 'August',
        'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'July'
    ],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(252,233,79,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(82,75,25,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(166,152,51,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0,39.0 ]

        }
    ]
}
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var opts = { 
       type: 'line', 
      data: data, 
       options: {} 
     };
new Chart(ctx, opts);
```

In Chart JS 1.0.2 the data Points are set correctly and the line is straight.

http://jsfiddle.net/AnchaXD/hg6f2fqo/

```
var data = {
    labels : ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'July', 'August',
        'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'July',
        'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'July', 'August',
        'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'July'
    ],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(252,233,79,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(82,75,25,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(166,152,51,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0,39.0 ]

        }
    ]
}

var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");


new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {});
```

I have already tried to fix this by Setting the Bezier Curve Tension to 0 and the cubicInterpolationMode to monotone.

Does anybody have the same Problem or any Idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.